# writing to a remote file on a pc from android emulator

Tags: java, android

Having problem with writing a string to the remote file from android emulator.
Nothing happens, no errors, no exceptions and no data written

This my code:

```
 urlFile  = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/remoteDB/dataEdit.txt" );
                         urlConn = urlFile.openConnection();
                               urlConn.setDoOutput(true); 


                         OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                             urlConn.getOutputStream());

                         PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(out);

                          out2.println("bla bla bla");
                           out2.flush();
                                               out2.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The http protocol (used in your URL) does not allow you to open a remote file to write into. In order to accomplish this, you need some CGI type of application on your PC's http server that bridges the gap.

Comment: sorry, but never had experience with, do u have any idea of how to write just a string to the file from emulator to pc?

Comment: I don't believe the emulator supports reaching out to the PC's file system directly. It does support emulation of an SD card though, and this emulated SD card is backed by a file on your PC's system. Johan's FTP approach is a good idea if you're able to place an FTP server on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ftp server on your pc and write to a file on the ftp server from your code. Its a really easy way to do it